# Fetch() async/await method in a local NextJs 13 app getting object “undefined”when trying to build for prod but works in dev

Tags: error-handling, next.js, build, fetch-api, next.js13

I’m learning NextJS 13 and trying out fetch()/async/await in a simple demo app running on a local Docker container. I’m using fetch()/async/await hitting a GraphQL api on another local container. Everything works great when running “npm run dev” and I’m now wanting to try out the workflow of Next’s static output and pushing to production but when I try generating the app via “npm run build” none of the api calls work because my code which is trying to display for example “data.item.name” and can’t select “item.name” on object “undefined” and the build fails. I retry running “npm run dev” and all works perfectly fine again.

I’ve double checked that my api is responding with Postman and all seems to be good. I did notice that when running the NextJS 13 app within Docker it wanted me to use the container ID of the api container ie “http://nginx/api” vs “http://localhost:8888” when making the fetch() call which had me hung up for a few days. But once I got that working the app and the fetch() calls worked great.

I’m brand new to Next and React so this one has really had me stuck.